# Problem uploading Mac catalyst binary to App Store connect

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, xcode11, mac-catalyst

I've added Mac capability to my app that's already on the App Store (iOS and iPad version) and I've also added a new platform for my app from App Store Connect. However, I'm unable to verify or upload a binary for the Mac platform (Catalyst project), as it always fails to verify with the following message:

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘’ is correct.

I've tried to create a second target with a new bundle id (maccatalyst.previous bundle id) to no avail.

Comment: Have you created mac version of your app in app store connect?

Comment: @emreoktem yes I have added a new platform to my app(Mac OS) and it's in the prepare for submission status, but I can't upload the Mac OS binary

Comment: No. I mean, have you created a completely new app (for Mac) in appstore connect?

Comment: no I thought I could just add a new version to my already available app to support Mac platform

Answer (score 1):

from the Xcode help section:

> CREATE A MAC VERSION OF AN IPAD APP
>
> About the Mac app built with Mac Catalyst bundle ID
>
> If you use Mac Catalyst to build a Mac version of an iPad app, you use
> the same bundle ID as the iPad app by default so you can distribute it
> as a universal purchase that allows customers to purchase the apps
> together from the App Store. Just add the macOS platform to an
> existing iPad app record in App Store Connect, then upload the builds
> separately.
>
> To distribute the apps separately, set a different bundle ID for the
> Mac app by unchecking the Use iOS Bundle Identifier checkbox, then
> create a separate app record for the Mac app in App Store Connect. If
> you have In-App Purchases or Subscriptions, recreate them for the Mac
> app in App Store Connect. Go to Create an in-app purchase and Create
> an auto-renewable subscription in App Store Connect Help.
>
> Configuring Projects Created Earlier Than Xcode 11.4 If you created
> the Mac app built with Mac Catalyst using an earlier Xcode release
> than 11.4, the Mac app and iPad app have different bundle IDs. The Mac
> app bundle ID has a maccatalyst prefix followed by the iPad app bundle
> ID by default. Use the Derive Mac Catalyst Product Bundle Identifier
> (DERIVE_MACCATALYST_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) build setting to
> configure your project:
>
> If you add an app extension, set the app extension target Derive Mac
> Catalyst Product Bundle Identifier build setting to YES because the
> Mac App Store requires that every embedded executable bundle have a
> bundle ID that is prefixed with the parent bundle ID.
>
> If you want to use universal purchase (use the same bundle ID for the
> Mac and iPad app), change the app Derive Mac Catalyst Product Bundle
> Identifier build setting from YES to NO.

Answer (score 0):

IOS and Mac apps are in different stores. So if you have an existing IOS app, you should also create a new Mac app in appstore connect and than upload your mac app.

Comment: so what is the use of the add platform button in the App Store connect ?